# Change value on legend in dc.js

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js, dc.js

I built a pie chart with dc.js, with the following:

```
var chart = dc.pieChart(selector, this.chartGroup)
  .width(200).height(200)
  .dimension(this.dimension)
  .group(this.group)
  ...
  .legend(dc.legend().x(10).y(255).gap(5).horizontal(true))

chart.render()
```

Is there a way to format the labels on the legend with something like the following:

```
function (d) {
  return d.key + ': ' + d.value;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The last answer seems partially true.  I would suggest the following:

```
    .legend(dc.legend().x(100).y(400).itemHeight(13).gap(5).autoItemWidth(true).legendText(function (d) {
        return d.name + " " + Math.round((d.data / totalPrice) * 100) + "%"
    }));
```

Where d.name is the actual label you will see in the legend.
d.data is the actual value.

Comment: [Not documented](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#dc.legend+x) but works.

Comment: How do you calculate variable ``totalPrice``

Comment: @Rusty: From @nico's answer below, you can use the following, although it does mean calculating the total value for each legend item: `d.chart.group().all().reduce(function(a, v){ return a + v.value; }, 0);`

Answer (score 3):

I also needed to add (%) to the pieChart legend for several graphs.  I ended up modifying a copy of the legend.js from dc.js-2.0.0-beta.5\src and include that in my pages.

See http://jsfiddle.net/za8ksj45/36/ for working example

```
    The first ~260 lines is the modified legend.js that can be put in a separate file.
    (I don't have a place I could serve it from so I had to include the file content).

    The main modification starts at line ~88

            itemEnter.append('text')
            .text(function(d) { 
                var legendText = d.name;
                if (_showPercent) {
                    var groupTotal = d.chart.group().all().reduce(function(a, v){ return a + v.value; }, 0);
                    //legendText = legendText + " (" + (100*d.data/groupTotal).toFixed(_percentDecimals) + "%)";
                    //legendText = legendText + " = " + (100*d.data/groupTotal).toFixed(_percentDecimals) + "%";
                    legendText = legendText + " - " + (100*d.data/groupTotal).toFixed(_percentDecimals) + "%";                                              
                }
                return legendText; 
            })
            .attr('x', _itemHeight + LABEL_GAP)
            .attr('y', function () {
                return _itemHeight / 2 + (this.clientHeight ? this.clientHeight : 13) / 2 - 2;
            });
```

The modification consists of two new methods for legend()

    .displayPercent     (default=false to keep original behavior the same)

    .percentDecimals    (default=1)

The hardest part to figure out was the following line:

```
 var groupTotal = d.chart.group().all().reduce(function(a, v){ return a + v.value; }, 0);
```

It calculates the grand total for the current filtered group that is driving the pieChart which can be used to calculate the percentage.

I played with a couple different string to show percentage.  It should probably be replaced with a string like this:  - (%%)   where %% gets replaced with the actual percentage.  That way you can customize it for each legend without having to touch the code.

Works great for a bunch of pieCharts I used so far.  I wanted to share this on stackoverflow since I have gotten so much help from this site myself.  If this is useful, I can expand it a bit and submit it for inclusion in some future release.

Comment: Its like four years after, but if you didn't submit this I think it would be a great addition to dcjs!

Answer (score 1):

Now you can simply use the `.legendText()` method in the `dc.legend()` object!

In your particular case, the solution would be:

```
var chart = dc.pieChart(selector, this.chartGroup)
  .width(200).height(200)
  .dimension(this.dimension)
  .group(this.group)
  ...
  .legend(dc.legend().x(10).y(255).gap(5).horizontal(true).legendText(function(d) {
    return d.key + ': ' + d.value;
  }))

chart.render();
```

This method is defined [here](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/src/legend.js#L253).